# R: cbind based on match first few letters or number of a cells

Tags: r, match

I have df1 like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(A=c("x01","x02","y03","z02","x04"), B=c("A01BB01","A02BB02","C02AA05","B04CC10","C01GX02"))

    A       B
1 x01 A01BB01
2 x02 A02BB02
3 y03 C02AA05
4 z02 B04CC10
5 x04 C01GX02
```

I have df2 like this.

```
  X     Y
1 a A01BB
2 b   A02
3 c  C02A
4 d   B04
5 e C01GX

df2 <- data.frame(X=c("a","b","c","d","e"), Y=c("A01BB","A02","C02A","B04","C01GX"))
```

I want to match the first few letters/ numbers in df1$B with those in df2$Y.  And then merge two dataframe based on the best match, as such, we expect to see a results data frame like this:

```
  A       B   X     Y
1 x01 A01BB01   a A01BB
2 x02 A02BB02   b   A02
3 y03 C02AA05   c  C02A
4 z02 B04CC10   d   B04
5 x04 C01GX02   e C01GX
```

Could you mind to teach me how to do so?  Thanks.

the Matching could only happens in the first few letters/number, the matched portion could not appear in the middle or the end of the words in df1$B, are there any effective way of doing this with R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pmatch` for this kind of matching:

```
with(c(df1,df2),{
  i <- pmatch(Y,B)
  data.frame(A,B,X = X[i],Y = Y[i])
})
```

Comment: Thank you.  Could you mind to teach me how to modify your code when df1 and df2 has different no. of rows?  Where it may also allow the matching to happen more than once, whenever, no match, "NA" should be given?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question - try replacing `data.frame` with `list` in the above code sample

Comment: Sorry that I did not give enough details in this question.  I have modified and post a modified detailed question as follow.  Please kindly give your comments.  @nullglob